# How to connet to the mysql server in zeit-now

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, vercel

I use [zeit-now](https://now.sh) to deploy my website.
But I can't connect to my MySQL server.
I'm sure my MySQL server is able to be connected on my machine.
Here is my [repo](https://github.com/zhmushan/ncc-with-nestjs-typeorm).
Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

In the FAQ it says

> Now itself focuses on being the best platform for serverless hosting. This means that the workloads we handle are static or stateless.

Still, you're trying to connect to your database on localhost. Although running a database instance in a docker container might be an option for a staging system, it definitely is not for production systems, since you will lose the data when you restart/redeploy. And you don't seem to startup a docker container in your deployment.

You should use a cloud database provider instead:

> Use Cloud Databases that offer secure (preferably HTTPS-based) gateways, for example: Azure CosmosDB, MongoDB, Atlas, Firebase, Google Cloud SQL

Comment: Hi, thx you and sorry for being late. I deployed the database on my cloud server.

Comment: So you deployed your database on Zeit? Via a docker container? Did you expose the port?

Comment: I purchased a cloud virtual machine and installed MySQL. I am able to connect through `mysql -u*** -p*** -h ***.***.***.***`. I can also use the typeorm connection locally, but on zeit, the typeorm connection fails.